# BackgroundWorker isn't working if I don't use Thread.Sleep on WinForms

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Here is my simple code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) return;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        worker?.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Completed.";
}
```

This code works correctly. But If I remove `Thread.Sleep(1);` from the code, BackgroundWorker does not work. I couldn't find where the error came from in such a simple thing.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? If you remove the Sleep you are flooding the UI thread with too many consecutive updates. It can't update so fast as the empty for-loop runs.

Comment: @Steeeve - That was enough to say. How can I know? The fact of the matter is: 1000 records are coming from the database. I add them to a list of objects and it is displayed in Gridview. Same thing happens in this case.

Comment: Without knowing the real code I can't say much. But, displaying 1000 records in a GridView may take more time than getting them from the databse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to report the progress so often.

Do something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    if (i % 100 == 0)
    {
        worker?.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

Or you could check the time or tickcount, and when you've seen 50ms of time has elapsed then do a `ReportProgress`. There's no point doing it more often than that.

Also, you could batch the updates to your `GridView` to make it more efficient/less wasteful - sending so many rows 1 row at a time is going to have more overhead doing it one at a time.